# Error - cannot get value when using variable at datetimepicker name

Tags: c#

I am using the following code,

I am getting error that timeStart is a null - it dont get its value.

no idea why is that...

here is the code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
    DateTimePicker timeStart = (DateTimePicker)this.Controls["datetimeBi"+i];
    MessageBox.Show(timeStart.Value.ToString());
}
```

i have tried also

```
DateTimePicker timeStart = (DateTimePicker)this.Controls["datetimeBi"+i.ToString()];
```

but it didnt worked also..

getting error always at the showbox becouse of the "no value" (NULL).

Comment: how are you adding the `DateTimePicker(s)`

Comment: what do u mean how i add the DateTimePicker(s)?

Comment: probably your Controls indexer this.Controls["datetimeBi"+i] returns you null; this can be because of wrong ID or because of your datetimepickers not a direct childs of 'this' (controls indexers are not recursive).

Comment: oh u were right, i put it inside a tab and didnt notice! thanks alot! my bad

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with the first approach. I presume you are trying to iterate over few `DataTimerPicker` controls. If so, can you check the `Name` property of each `DataTimerPicker` control instances. I suppose it should be, datetimeBi1,datetimeBi2,datetimeBi3 ( just guessing after seeing your code).

Meantime, you can also check the immediate parent of your child controls ( DateTimePicker).

Comment: the names were right, i was sure i put put the DateTimePickers under the main form, but i put them under a tab thats was the issue, thanks alot to every1 :)